# Why does $[Q,P]=i\hbar$ work for fermion? Shouldn't fermion satisfy anticommuting relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, fermions, hydrogen, anticommutator

For hydrogen, we use $[Q,P]=i\hbar$ for electron, which is a fermion. Does it have a deeper reason such as that we're really considering the proton + electron system, which might be of bosonic nature?

Comment: This is not a dumb question, but I think you are mixing up some concepts. For $N$ distinguishable particles, we have the corresponding operators $X_n$, $P_n$, for $n=1,2,\ldots, N$, where $[X_n,P_m]=i\delta_{nm}$. For indistinguishable particles, the operators $X_n$, $P_n$ are no valid operators and observables on the corresponding Hilbert spaces, because they are not permutation invariant. You can build e.g. the total momentum as a valid observable, though, and which is given by $P=\sum_{n=1}^N P_n=\sum\limits_{k} k a^\dagger_k a_k$. (I've set $\hbar=1$ everywhere)

Comment: Also $Q,P$ are position and momentum operators, what you refer to is due to the spin-statistics theorem. The fermion anti commutation is rooted in their creation/annihilation operators

Comment: This commutation relation is valid for any quantum particle with mass irrespective of whether that particle's nature.

Comment: All of the responses are circular.  It works because it agrees with experiment. All the theoretical framework discussion below relies on theory that was created out of a certain set of experimental results. The theory doesn't exist independently.

Comment: @JQK  No. The question asks about consistency of the theory, not why e.g. the commutation is supposed to hold (where, as you correctly point out, the ultimate answer, to this or some equivalent question, must be: because if we do so, we can make good predictions for experiments)

Comment: The question ask why we use a certain commutation relation.  There isn't an independent explanation apart from the experiment that motivates the theory.    There's no shortage of interesting theoretical ideas that had to be abandoned because they didn't agree with experiment, Bohr's model of the atom, etc.  Historically, the commutation relates were used because it help to explain spectra.  The theoretical framework that developed afterwards has it baked into it. This isn't a "which came first" issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a consistent picture using second quantisation. In general, you can promote a first quantised operator:
$$
O^1 = \sum O_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|
$$
to a second quantised operator:
$$
O^2 = \sum O_{ij}c_i^\dagger c_j
$$
which you interpret being the original operator weighted by the distribution of particles in the orbitals.

If you're describing fermions, then the creation/annihilation operators satisfy the CAR's:
$$
\{c_i,c_j^\dagger\} = \delta_{ij}
$$
This suffices to show that the mapping conserves commutators:
$$
\begin{align}
[A^2,B^2] &= \sum A_{ij}B_{kl}[c_i^\dagger c_j,c_k^\dagger c_l] \\
&= \sum A_{ij}B_{kl}(\delta_{jk}c_i^\dagger c_l-\delta_{il}c^\dagger_kc_j) \\
&=  \sum (A_{ik}B_{kj}-B_{ik}A_{kj})c_i^\dagger c_j \\
&= [A^1,B^1]^2
\end{align}
$$
Note that the key property:
$$
[c_i^\dagger c_j,c_k^\dagger c_l] = \delta_{jk}c_i^\dagger c_l-\delta_{il}c^\dagger_kc_j
$$
is also valid for bosons satisfying the CCR's, so the result still applies. This is why you can basically identify an annihilation as a ket and a creation as a bra.

Coming back to your electrons, you can similarly define in 1D (setting $\hbar=1$):
$$
\begin{align}
X &= \int xc_x^\dagger c_x dx\\
&= -\int i\frac{dc_p^\dagger}{dp} c_p dp \\
P &= \int pc_p^\dagger c_p \frac{dp}{2\pi} \\
&= \int i\frac{dc_x^\dagger}{dx} c_x dx \\
\end{align}
$$
so $[X,P] = in$ with $n=\int c_x^\dagger c_x dx = \int c_p^\dagger c_p \frac{dp}{2\pi}$ with:
$$
\{c_x,c_y^\dagger\} = \delta(x-y)\\
\{c_p,c_q^\dagger\} = 2\pi\delta(p-q)
$$
Note that you must be careful with the interpretation of momentum. The kinetic energy is not $P^2/2$, but rather:
$$
H_k = \int \frac{p^2}{2}c_p^\dagger c_p \frac{dp}{2\pi} \\
$$

In the case of non-interacting particles, this allows you to reduce a second quantisation problem into a first quantisation problem, and you just need to determine the filling of the orbitals.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

The commutation relation is non-relativistic quantum mechanics, which is applied to a single "particle", where a "particle" really means a wave function. (Pauli) spin is an after-thought required by experiment, and as far as I know, the antisymmetry of a multi-(identical)-particle state is a phenomenological constraint. (Also, I've found that thinking about a particle in QM is not helpful, it leads to these visuals where the electron is randomly popping around it's orbital in a "probability cloud"...just stop at the wave-function, which is a probability amplitude [read: not-at-all intuitive], and accept the fact that is an abstraction that works).

Dirac spin is absolutely fundamental, as is the spin-statistics theorem, which is famously non-intuitive, but it's driven by preserving causality (no space-like correlations...irrc).

Since $c$ does not appear in the Schrödinger Equation, there is nothing to prevent FTL physics, so none of the relativistic QFT stuff applies, unless we apply it after-the-fact.

Comment: pls comment when down voting.